# An empty awk variable with disk size

Tags: linux, bash

To limit the recording through the dd command, I decided to create a variable with the disk size, but when entering any disk in the variable, the volume of all disks that are in the system appears

```
#!/bin/bash
drivelist=$(lsblk --nodeps --noheadings --output TRAN,NAME,SIZE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT | nl)
echo -n "$drivelist
Select $disk:"
read disk
blk=$(lsblk | awk -v disk="$disk" '/disk/ {printf "%.0f\n", $4}' | tr -d 'M|G|T')
echo "$blk"
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample of your `lsblk` output, an example value for the `awk` variable `disk`, and the expected result (corresponding to the sample `lsblk` output)

Comment: `/disk/` says to look for the literal string `'disk'` in the current line; to look for the contents of an `awk` variable in the current line => change `/disk/` to `$0 ~ disk` and see if that generates what you're looking for